# View Pager - based on condition check, not to add few items

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have an array list and I want to do this logic

In the pager Adapter -

```
     getCount() returns arrayList.size()
```

In the PagerAdapter - istantiateItem()

```
 if(condition met)

          add item to view

          return view
else 
    return null
```

When I do that - whenever condition is not met , I see a blank item on the View Pager. How to not add a blank item to View Pager.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `getCount()` method as well as `getItem()` method with your condition check.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    int size = 0;
    for (Fragment fragment: fragmentList) {
        if (fragment.isOK()) {
            size++;
        }
    }
    return size;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position){
    int index = 0;
    for (Fragment fragment: fragmentList) {
        if (fragment.isOK()) {
            if(index == position){
                return fragment;
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```